# MatTableDataSource not showing data from file readed with exceljs lib

Tags: angular, mat-table, exceljs

I'm trying to show data into a Mat Table from a xlsx file readed with exceljs library.
I think i'm filling the MatTableDataSource correctly, but nothing is showing on the screen.

This is the TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator'
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table'
import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js'


export interface Colaborador{
  Rut: string
  Rol: string
  Nombres: string
  Apellidos: string
  Departamento: string
  Empresa: string
  Cargo: string
  Existe: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-trabajador-create-masive',
  templateUrl: './trabajador-create-masive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trabajador-create-masive.component.css']
})
export class TrabajadorCreateMasiveComponent implements OnInit {
  
  listadoTrabajadores:MatTableDataSource<Colaborador>
  displayedColumns:string[] = ["Rut","Rol","Nombre","Departamento","Empresa","Cargo"]

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  procesarArchivo(event){
    const file=event.target.files[0]
    let fileData:Colaborador[]=[]

    fileData=this.leerArchivo(file)
    console.log(fileData)

    this.listadoTrabajadores = new MatTableDataSource(fileData)
    this.listadoTrabajadores.paginator=this.paginator
  }

  leerArchivo(Archivo):Colaborador[]{
    let fileData:Colaborador[]=[]
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook()
    const arryBuffer = new Response(Archivo).arrayBuffer()

    arryBuffer.then(function (data) {
       workbook.xlsx.load(data).then(function () {
        const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1)
        worksheet.eachRow(function (row, rowNumber) {
          if(rowNumber>1){
            fileData.push({
              Rut: row.getCell(1).toString(),
              Rol: row.getCell(2).toString(),
              Nombres: row.getCell(3).toString(),
              Apellidos: row.getCell(4).toString(),
              Departamento: row.getCell(5).toString(),
              Empresa: row.getCell(6).toString(),
              Cargo: row.getCell(7).toString(),
              Existe: false
            })
          }
        })
      })
    })
    
    return fileData
  }

}
```

The template code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="listadoTrabajadores" style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Rut">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Rut</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Rut | rut }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Rol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Rol</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Rol }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Nombre">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Nombre</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Nombres }} {{ data.Apellidos }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Departamento">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Departamento</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Departamento }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Empresa">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Empresa</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Empresa }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Cargo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content:center">Cargo</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{ data.Cargo }} </td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let data; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[20,50,100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

And this is what i'm seeing on the screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waSwC.png)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

edit:
here is an image of debugging procesarArchivo() with the subscribe method, retrieven no data from leerArchivo(), but console.log is showing data

[image: debuggin procesarArchivo()]

Comment: Can you share the template code as well?

Comment: sure... post edited :)

Answer (score 0):

With the current code, the data source is being assigned an empty `fileData` array since function `leerArchivo()` returns after the data source is assigned.

Provided you have data loading from your Excel file into the `arryBuffer` and `worksheet` variables and your `fileData` array has populated data, then applying the following recommended minor change with one of the two equivalent methods as follows will remediate the issue:

**Subscribe Method**

a. Change the return type of your function `leerArchivo()` and return `fileData` as an observable as shown:

```
leerArchivo(Archivo): Observable<Colaborador[]> {
  let fileData: Colaborador[] = [];
  ..
  ..
  return of(fileData);
}
```

b. Apply the following changes to your `procesarArchivo()` method to subscribe to the `leerArchivo()` function:

```
procesarArchivo(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let fileData: Colaborador[] = [];

  this.leerArchivo(file).subscribe((res) => {
    fileData = res;
    this.listadoTrabajadores = new MatTableDataSource(fileData);
    this.listadoTrabajadores.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log(fileData);
  });
}
```

**Async/Await**

a. Make your function `leerArchivo()` asynchonous, change it's return type to a `Promise` and return `fileData` as a promise as shown:

```
async leerArchivo(Archivo): Promise<Colaborador[]> {
  let fileData: Colaborador[] = [];
  ...
  ...     
  return await Promise.resolve(fileData);
}
```

b. Apply the following changes to your `procesarArchivo()` method to invoke the `leerArchivo()` asynchronous function:

```
procesarArchivo(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let fileData: Colaborador[] = [];
  this.leerArchivo(file).then((res) => {
    fileData = res;
    this.listadoTrabajadores = new MatTableDataSource(fileData);
    this.listadoTrabajadores.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log(fileData);
  });
}
```

With the above changes your data source `listadoTrabajadores` for the Material table that is referenced within your component template will be correctly assigned with `fileData` after it has been retrieved from the Excel file.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your answer.
I tryed both methods, but getting the same results :/

Comment: Can you try debugging the leerArchivo() method using console logs to verify the Excel data is correctly loading or just return a single mock record from it and see if it assigns to fileData (in procesarArchivo()) and the HTML output. You will also need to execute  procesarArchivo() somewhere within your component template or external to it.

Comment: I aplied debugger to procesarArchivo() with subscribe method, and efectively no data is returned, but the console.log is showing the data, as if was returned correctly from leerArchivo()
I posted an image at the end of the question with this case